# Success message won't disappear in the home page Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

When I try to use the LUMA Theme, the success message is working properly, but when I use the custom theme, that's where the problem starts. The success message accumulates in the home page whenever I try to add a product to the compare list. I'm using Magento 2.1.3. See the picture below:[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your's theme do some thing with section update process on frontend. You should look at file 
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/view/customer.js
and add condition and do force refresh of the sections

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var someCondition = true;

            this.customer = customerData.get('customer');
            if(someCondition === true){
            customerData.reload(['customer']);
            }
        }
    });
});
```